# Outlook: Change calendar color

Tags: vba, colors, calendar, outlook, vsto

Is it possible to change the color of calendar folder in Outlook 2007/2010 through VBA/VSTO? Note that I'm not talking about appointments color, which can be set using categories. To see what I mean, go to Calendar tab in Outlook, right-click on a calendar and choose Color menu. You'll get a fixed list of options. I want to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is [not currently possible to assign the background color of Calendar folder or items](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/outlookdev/thread/65ec9b9f-e80c-48f0-8c9d-e02f7a1e5c1a) using `Outlook.CalendarView`. MS has chose not so support this feature programmatically yet - they only expose it via the UI using **Calendar Default Display Options** and **Calendar Color Properties**.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer. Although there's an XML property of the View object that Microsoft says can be used to customize the appearence of Outlook Views, I could get it to work. There's no other "direct" property to change the background color.